# Choosing the active selection tool

Tags: selection-tools, select

I am new to Blender, and I keep running into a problem with 2.8. I use the LMB to select, because it feels more natural to me. When I am modeling, I sometimes (probably due to accidental hotkeys) end up with my active selection tool on the left menu being circle select instead of box select. I cannot find any intuitive way to change which selection tool is listed on the left menu, and therefore which one I can use as my active tool in the n-menu. This has been very frustrating, so any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I realized that the arrow below the select tool is not a menu to be clicked, but rather is one that must be dragged out. It then lets you change.